# How do I join 3 tables using linq syntax

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my code:

```
// Put together a list of new communities
var communityList = from x in db.CommunityTeams
                    join y in db.Communities on x.CommunityId equals y.CommunityId 
                    join z in db.CommunityRoles on x.CommunityRole equals z.Role
                    where x.UserId == userId 
                    select new
                    {
                        CommunityName = y.ComunityName,
                        CommunityRoleName = z.Role       
                    };
```

The join z in db.CommunityRoles is giving me this error:

the Join clause in incorrect. How do I get the syntax correct?

Comment: Giving you what error?

Comment: Please show your model structure and the error you are getting.

Comment: The error I am getting is "the Join clause is incorrect"

Comment: Please provide the SQL table structure if possible, or at least the Linq2Sql definitions

Comment: 1. Use navigation properties, not joins. 2. You can output `x.CommunityRole` instead of `z.Role` so you don't need `db.CommunityRoles`.

Comment: @PaulT.Rykiel if you have solved the problem, please update the question to include the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax isn't incorrect. The tables you are joining with columns `x.CommunityRole` and `z.Role` are not in the same type.

> Error  CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

You have probably getting this error and you have to join columns with same types for example `int` and `int`. Check both of them must be same.

Comment: Thanks for your help, as it turned out I had the CommunityRole data already in the model in entity framework, because I created a foreign key contraint, so when I loaded it, there was a collection of CommunityRoles on the CommunityTeams that I could pull in from the model, so no join was required.